# parse a XML and store into a table

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing

I have a xml as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cus:request xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.bt.com/btgs/solutions/message/customerRequest C:\SalesSchema_Latest\RequestManagementV1.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:sortarg="http://www.bt.com/btgs/solutions/library/SourceAndTarget"
    xmlns:siteType="http://www.bt.com/btgs/solutions/library/SiteType"
    xmlns:reqType="http://www.bt.com/btgs/solutions/library/RequestType"
    <sourceSystem name="Resign Tool" type="LQTWebsite" />
    <targetSystem  name="MESSIA" type="Sales Tools" />
    <changeRequest customerRequestRef="" BTProjectManagementRef="">
        <customerOrganisation orgID="ID000001" orgInternalID="29823" resignInstanceType="Source">
            <organisationName>BT PLC</organisationName>
            <contactInfo contactID="ID000002">
                <role>CUSTOMER</role>
                <position />
                <fullName />
                <telephone />
                <fax />
                <email />
                <contactAddress>
                    <room />
                    <floor />
                    <building />
                    <streetNumber />
                    <streetName />
                    <locality />
                    <city />
                    <county-state />
                    <country ISOCountryCode="" />
                    <postcode />
                </contactAddress>
            </contactInfo>
        </customerOrganisation>
        <customerOrganisation orgID="ID000003" orgInternalID="29823" resignInstanceType="Target">
            <organisationName>BT PLC</organisationName>
            <contactInfo contactID="ID000004">
                <role>CUSTOMER</role>
                <position />
                <fullName />
                <telephone />
                <fax />
                <email />
                <contactAddress>
                    <building />
                    <streetNumber />
                    <streetName />
                    <city />
                    <county-state />
                    <country />
                    <postcode />
                </contactAddress>
            </contactInfo>
        </customerOrganisation>
        <billTo siteID="ID000005">
            <organisation>
                <organisationRef>ID000003</organisationRef>
            </organisation>
            <bilingContact contactID="ID000006">
                <role>Billing</role>
                <position />
                <fullName />
                <telephone />
                <fax />
                <email />
                <contactAddress>
                    <room />
                    <floor />
                    <building />
                    <streetNumber />
                    <streetName />
                    <city />
                    <county-state />
                    <country ISOCountryCode="" />
                    <postcode />
                </contactAddress>
            </bilingContact>
        </billTo>
        <defaultContract contractID="ID000007" contractInternalID="547386" resignInstanceType="Source">
            <contractReference>BTIM789456</contractReference>
            <contractDuration>1</contractDuration>
            <billingFrequency>Monthly</billingFrequency>
        </defaultContract>
        <defaultContract contractID="ID000008" contractInternalID="547386" resignInstanceType="Target">
            <contractReference>BTIM789457</contractReference>
            <contractDuration>1</contractDuration>
            <billingFrequency>Monthly</billingFrequency>
        </defaultContract>
        <billOfMaterials>
            <bomSiteItem siteID="ID000009" siteInternalID="1163642" BTSiteType="host">
                <organisation>
                    <organisationRef>ID000003</organisationRef>
                </organisation>
                <siteContact>
                    <role />
                    <firstName />
                    <lastName />
                    <telephone />
                    <mobile />
                    <fax />
                    <email />
                </siteContact>
                <siteName>BIRMINGHAM_001</siteName>
                <siteReference>ID000009</siteReference>
                <siteAddress>
                    <room />
                    <floor />
                    <building>BT BUILDING</building>
                    <streetNumber>5</streetNumber>
                    <streetName>BRINDLEY PLACE</streetName>
                    <locality>BIRMINGHAM</locality>
                    <city>BIRMINGHAM</city>
                    <county-state>WEST MIDLANDS</county-state>
                    <country ISOCountryCode="">UNITED KINGDOM</country>
                    <postcode>B1 2BL</postcode>
                </siteAddress>
                <coordinates  gridSystem="easting-and-northing">
                    <x-coordinate />
                    <y-coordinate />
                </coordinates >
                <installationLocation locID="ID000010">
                    <subPremise>FLOOR 3 ROOM 6</subPremise>
                </installationLocation>
                <siteItem lineItemID="ID000011">
                    <itemContract contractID="ID000012">
                        <matrixType>Fixed Link WAN</matrixType>
                        <contractNumber />
                        <contractReference>BTIM789456</contractReference>
                        <contractDuration>1</contractDuration>
                        <contractSignedDate>2015-07-31</contractSignedDate>
                    </itemContract>
                    <orderItemAction majorOrderAction="resign" minorOrderAction="resign" />
                    <itemQuantity>1</itemQuantity>
                    <prod:product xsi:type="prod:CPEproductType"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" instanceID="ID000013" internalInventoryID="7236799">
                        <productID>803624</productID>
                        <productDescription>NORTEL CS1000 / MERIDIAN</productDescription>
                        <aEndSite>
                            <siteRef>ID000009</siteRef>
                            <locRef>ID000010</locRef>
                            <installationLocation>
                                <cabinet />
                                <room />
                                <floor />
                            </installationLocation>
                        </aEndSite>
                        <CPEProductSpecificDetails>
                            <param>TEST</param>
                            <stringValue>Test</stringValue>
                        </CPEProductSpecificDetails>
                    </prod:product>
                </siteItem>
                <siteItem lineItemID="ID000014">
                    <itemContract contractID="ID000015">
                        <matrixType>Fixed Link WAN</matrixType>
                        <contractNumber />
                        <contractReference>BTIM789456</contractReference>
                        <contractDuration>1</contractDuration>
                        <contractSignedDate>2015-07-31</contractSignedDate>
                    </itemContract>
                    <orderItemAction majorOrderAction="resign" minorOrderAction="resign" />
                    <itemQuantity>1</itemQuantity>
                    <prod:product xsi:type="prod:CPEitemType"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" instanceID="ID000016" internalInventoryID="7236800">
                        <productID>720056</productID>
                        <productType />
                        <productDescription>TMP-00003</productDescription>
                        <BTitemCode>711875</BTitemCode>
                        <installationCPEID>ID000013</installationCPEID>
                    </prod:product>
                </siteItem>

                <siteItem lineItemID="ID000143">
                    <itemContract contractID="ID000144">
                        <matrixType>Fixed Link WAN</matrixType>
                        <contractNumber />
                        <contractReference>BTIM789456</contractReference>
                        <contractDuration>1</contractDuration>
                        <contractSignedDate>2015-07-31</contractSignedDate>
                    </itemContract>
                    <orderItemAction majorOrderAction="resign" minorOrderAction="resign" />
                    <itemQuantity>1</itemQuantity>
                    <prod:product xsi:type="prod:serviceWrapType" instanceID="ID000145" internalInventoryID="7235310"
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <ruleID>62522</ruleID>
                        <productID>319819</productID>
                        <productDescription>Standard Care</productDescription>
                        <aEndSite>
                            <siteRef>ID000009</siteRef>
                            <locRef>ID000010</locRef>
                            <installationLocation>
                                <cabinet />
                                <room />
                                <floor />
                            </installationLocation>
                        </aEndSite>
                        <associatedCPEID>ID000067</associatedCPEID>
                        <serviceWrapProductSpecificDetails>
                            <param attributeID="3772">BT ALIAS</param>
                            <integerValue>7235310</integerValue>
                            <param attributeID="2655">CONTRACT LINK</param>
                            <integerValue>547386</integerValue>
                            <param attributeID="318">EQUIPMENT LINK</param>
                            <integerValue>7236817</integerValue>
                            <param attributeID="318">EQUIPMENT LINK</param>
                            <integerValue>7236817</integerValue>
                            <param attributeID="318">EQUIPMENT LINK</param>
                            <integerValue>7236817</integerValue>
                            <param attributeID="9553">IS THIS PART OF MANAGEMENT BUNDLE</param>
                            <stringValue>NO</stringValue>
                            <param attributeID="3771">SOURCE SYSTEM</param>
                            <stringValue>EXPEDIO</stringValue>
                        </serviceWrapProductSpecificDetails>
                    </prod:product>
                </siteItem>

            </bomSiteItem>



        </billOfMaterials>
    </changeRequest>
</cus:request>
```

I want to parse the whole xml and get the values of "contactid", "role", "position"  and few more for all contactid and store it into a table .
How can this be achieved.

I have tried using

```
   set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
  x XMLType := XMLType(
    ' <changeRequest customerRequestRef="" BTProjectManagementRef="">
        <customerOrganisation orgID="ID000001" orgInternalID="29823" resignInstanceType="Source">
            <organisationName>BT PLC</organisationName>
            <contactInfo contactID="ID000002">
                <role>CUSTOMER</role>
                <position />
                <fullName />
                <telephone />
                <fax />
                <email />
                <contactAddress>
                    <room />
                    <floor />
                    <building />
                    <streetNumber />
                    <streetName />
                    <locality />
                    <city />
                    <county-state />
                    <country ISOCountryCode="" />
                    <postcode />
                </contactAddress>
            </contactInfo>
        </customerOrganisation>
        <customerOrganisation orgID="ID000003" orgInternalID="29823" resignInstanceType="Target">
            <organisationName>BT PLC</organisationName>
            <contactInfo contactID="ID000004">
                <role>CUSTOMER</role>
                <position />
                <fullName />
                <telephone />
                <fax />
                <email />
                <contactAddress>
                    <building />
                    <streetNumber />
                    <streetName />
                    <city />
                    <county-state />
                    <country />
                    <postcode />
                </contactAddress>
            </contactInfo>
        </customerOrganisation>
        </changeRequest>');


BEGIN
  For R In (
    SELECT ExtractValue(Value(p),'/changeRequest/customerOrganisation/contactInfo/role/text()') as name

    FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/changeRequest'))) p
    ) LOOP

   dbms_output.put_line(r.name); 
  End Loop;
  Exception
   When Others then
    dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
END;
```

But it throws an exception **ORA-19025: EXTRACTVALUE returns value of only one node**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XMLSequence - is deprecated.Try xmltable [XMLTABLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm#SQLRF06232).

To access xml elmeent attribute use "@attrname"

```
 select * from xmltable('/changeRequest/customerOrganisation' passing XMLType(
    ' <changeRequest customerRequestRef="" BTProjectManagementRef="">
        <customerOrganisation orgID="ID000001" orgInternalID="29823" resignInstanceType="Source">
            <organisationName>BT PLC</organisationName>
            <contactInfo contactID="ID000002">
                <role>CUSTOMER</role>
                <position />
                <fullName />
                <telephone />
                <fax />
                <email />
                <contactAddress>
                    <room />
                    <floor />
                    <building />
                    <streetNumber />
                    <streetName />
                    <locality />
                    <city />
                    <county-state />
                    <country ISOCountryCode="" />
                    <postcode />
                </contactAddress>
            </contactInfo>
        </customerOrganisation>
        <customerOrganisation orgID="ID000003" orgInternalID="29823" resignInstanceType="Target">
            <organisationName>BT PLC</organisationName>
            <contactInfo contactID="ID000004">
                <role>CUSTOMER</role>
                <position />
                <fullName />
                <telephone />
                <fax />
                <email />
                <contactAddress>
                    <building />
                    <streetNumber />
                    <streetName />
                    <city />
                    <county-state />
                    <country />
                    <postcode />
                </contactAddress>
            </contactInfo>
        </customerOrganisation>
        </changeRequest>')
        columns orgID varchar2(100) path './@orgID'
           ,  contactID varchar2(100) path './contactInfo/@contactID'
           ,  role varchar2(100) path './contactInfo/role'
        )
```

Comment: This works for me Thanks! I never thought of XMLTable.Now I want to create a procedure which excepts the xml as input and get the values into some variables so that it can be inserted into a table.

Comment: If I use my complete XML it throws an error "ORA-01704: string literal too long"

Comment: Your xml is to long. You have to split whole xml into varcahr2 chunck and append this chunk into clob variable.

Answer (score 1):

you should add customerOrganisation into XMLSequence. 
Because you have some organisations for each change request
It works:

```
DECLARE
  x XMLType := XMLType(
    ' <changeRequest customerRequestRef="" BTProjectManagementRef="">
        <customerOrganisation orgID="ID000001" orgInternalID="29823" resignInstanceType="Source">
            <organisationName>BT PLC</organisationName>
            <contactInfo contactID="ID000002">
                <role>CUSTOMER</role>
                <position />
                <fullName />
                <telephone />
                <fax />
                <email />
                <contactAddress>
                    <room />
                    <floor />
                    <building />
                    <streetNumber />
                    <streetName />
                    <locality />
                    <city />
                    <county-state />
                    <country ISOCountryCode="" />
                    <postcode />
                </contactAddress>
            </contactInfo>
        </customerOrganisation>
        <customerOrganisation orgID="ID000003" orgInternalID="29823" resignInstanceType="Target">
            <organisationName>BT PLC</organisationName>
            <contactInfo contactID="ID000004">
                <role>CUSTOMER</role>
                <position />
                <fullName />
                <telephone />
                <fax />
                <email />
                <contactAddress>
                    <building />
                    <streetNumber />
                    <streetName />
                    <city />
                    <county-state />
                    <country />
                    <postcode />
                </contactAddress>
            </contactInfo>
        </customerOrganisation>
        </changeRequest>');

    BEGIN
      For R In (
           SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(Value(p),'/customerOrganisation/contactInfo/role/text()') as role,
           EXTRACTVALUE(Value(p),'/customerOrganisation/contactInfo/position/text()') as position,
           EXTRACTVALUE(Value(p),'/customerOrganisation/contactInfo/@contactID') as contactID
        FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(x,'/changeRequest/customerOrganisation'))) p
        ) LOOP

       dbms_output.put_line(r.role || '  ' || r.position  || '  ' || r.contactID); 
      End Loop;
      Exception
       When Others then
        dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    END;
```

Comment: doesnt' give any value if I use dbms_output.put_line(r.role);

Comment: If I use my complete XML it throws an error "string literal too long". The xml size is 140000 characters.

Comment: XMLType constructor pass as parameter - varchar2. Max size of them - only 32k. I suppose you should create new question and discuss it separately

Comment: As idea, I can suggest to create new table with one XMLType column and put your xml directly via your editor (SQL Developer, PlSQL Developer, Toad or something else). 
After  declare x XMLType;
select xml_type_column into x from your_table;